# How can I write Persian text to PDF programmatically?

Tags: java, android, pdf

I write a program that creates a PDF file to SD-Card. Then it writes some text to it. I want to write some Persian text to that but the text isn't shown in the PDF.
Here is my android codes :

```
// Create a document and set it's properties
Document objDocument = new Document();

objDocument.setCreator("اپلیکیشن فرهنگیان");
objDocument.setAuthor("فرهنگیان");
objDocument.setTitle("تاریخچه اپلیکیشن فرهنگیان");

// Create a page to add to the document
Page objPage = new Page(PageSize.LETTER, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, 54.0f);

printstr = "این یک متن تستی است ." ;
Label objLabel = new Label(printstr, 0, 0, 504, 100, 
    Font.getHelvetica(), 18, TextAlign.RIGHT);

// Add label to page
objPage.getElements().add(objLabel);

// Add page to document
objDocument.getPages().add(objPage);

try {
    // Outputs the document to file
    objDocument.draw(FILE);
    Toast.makeText(this, "فایل متنی در مسیر  :" + FILE + " ذخیره شد .",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "فایل ساخته نمیشود\n" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

What is problem ?

Comment: Do you already changed the charset?

Comment: No . how can i change it ?

Comment: Can you help me , please ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see where you specify PDF format, try implementing to your code

```
// open a new document
PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context,
     printAttributes);

// start a page
Page page = document.startPage(0);

// draw something on the page
View content = getContentView();
content.draw(page.getCanvas());

// finish the page
document.finishPage(page);
. . .
// add more pages
. . .
// write the document content
document.writeTo(getOutputStream());

//close the document
document.close();
```

SRC: [AndroidDevelopers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html)